# Is it possible to find whitespace after some string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to get is to find all whitespaces after some string eg. "abc" like this:

```
Abcabcabc ab abc babcba.
         ^      ^
```

Only what I can do is to find strings "abc " with regex

```
/abc\s/g
```

But I want to get only a space after "abc".

Is it even possible? It is important to me because then I can use this i JS

```
text.replace(REGEX, "something");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible because javascript's regex engine doesn't support look behinds. But you can just capture `abc` and use it in replace string.

```
text.replace(/(abc)\s/g, "$1something");
```

Basically you're achieving the same thing. `$1` refers to the first group that's been captured by paranthesis You can also hard-code replace string like

```
text.replace(/abc\s/g, "abcsomething");
```

Comment: @user4230877 glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds in regular expressions. However, it supports lookaheads. So you can reverse your string and use a lookahead:

```
text.split('').reverse().join('')   // Invert string
.replace(/\s(?=cba)/g, 'gnihtemos') // Use lookahead
.split('').reverse().join('');      // Invert again
```

Comment: In this case, AmitJoki's answer is much simpler, though.